# 'PedidoComissaoAdmin.date_hierarchy' refers to field 'pedido__data' that is missing from model 'PedidoComissao'

Tags: python, django

In models.py

```
class PedidoComissao(models.Model):
    artista = models.ForeignKey(Cliente, verbose_name='Artista')
    pedido = models.ForeignKey(Pedido)
    pedidoitem = models.ForeignKey(PedidoItem, verbose_name='Arte')
    valor_receber = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=2)
    data_pagamento = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    origem_venda = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=30)

class Meta:
    verbose_name, verbose_name_plural = u'Comissão', u'Comissões'
```

In admin.py

```
class PedidoComissaoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['artista', 'pedido', 'pedido_data',
                    'pedidoitem', 'valor_receber', 'data_pagamento',
                    'status', 'origem_venda']
    list_filter = ['artista__nome', 'pedido__data']
    actions = ['status_pago']
    date_hierarchy = 'pedido__data'

def pedido_data(self, instance):
    return instance.pedido.data.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
```

I get error as:

```
'PedidoComissaoAdmin.date_hierarchy' refers to field 'pedido__data' that is missing from model 'PedidoComissao'.
```

date_hierarchy with foreign key not working?
I can not use a date field with foreign key?

Comment: I can not use the date field as it is the model order

Comment: What's the definition of the Pedido model? Does it have a field called data?

Comment: `class Pedido(models.Model):
 """(Pedido description)"""
 
 # DATA E STATUS DO PEDIDO
 data = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
 `